# Union replacing row if id is the same

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have 2 different tables with same data structure, table A and B, is it possible to get values from A and then B where if the ID entry exists in B it replaces the value got in A?

Example:

```sql
select '1' as id, 'Bob' as "user" from dual
union
select '1' as id, 'Alice' as "user" from dual
```

This returns:

```
1   Bob
1   Alice
```

If `id` is the same in the second select I would like to have only one row:

```
1   Alice
```

Comment: This sounds like something for an outer join instead of a union to me.

Comment: Do a JOIN with update.

Comment: if your table is `user`, it makes no sense perform an `union` operation to get all the Id's with your condition. What does it mean first and second for you?

Comment: @James "user" isn't a table, it's a column name. The two tables are represented in the example by inline select statements, selecting from "dual" because Oracle doesn't allow a select statement with no table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than a UNION, you need a "FULL OUTER JOIN", which will give you three types of row:

- Rows where both tables have a matching id, with values from both tables (the rows which an INNER JOIN would return)
- Rows where only table A has that id, with null for table B's columns (the additional rows which a LEFT OUTER JOIN would return)
- Rows where only table B has that id, with null for table A's columns (the additional rows which a RIGHT OUTER JOIN would return)

You can then use COALESCE to take the values from B if present (the first and second type of row), and A if not (the third type of row).

So for your example:

```sql
Select
    Coalesce(B.id, A.id) as id,
    Coalesce(B."user", A."user") as "user"
From
    (select '1' as id, 'Bob' as "user" from dual) as A
Full Outer Join
    (select '1' as id, 'Alice' as "user" from dual) as B
    On B.id = A.id
```

Which returns:

| id | user |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |

(Note: tested on SQL Server, by removing the "from dual", because I have no Oracle DB to test on.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

```
select '1' as id, 'Bob' as "user" from table_A
where id not in (select id from table_B)
union all
select '1' as id, 'Alice' as "user" from table_B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way using the ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY id order by tab)
where "tab" is the table name, in this example data from table_a will get priority and will be picked up.

```
create table table_a as 
(
select '1' as id, 'Bob' as "user" from dual
UNION
select '2' as id, 'Jack' as "user" from dual
) ;

create table table_b as 
(
select '1' as id, 'Alice' as "user" from dual -- table 
UNION
select '3' as id, 'John' as "user" from dual -- table
) ;

select * from (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY id order by tab) rnum,id, "user"
 from( 
select id, "user", 'A' tab from table_a 
union all
select id, "user", 'b' tab from table_b  
) 
) WHERE RNUM = 1;
```